# ZFS on >2TB disk in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gpt, zfs

I just got a 4TB disk and I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/2tb-gtp-parted/ says you need to partition your disk with GPT if you want to use >2TB (and that you can do this with fdisk/gparted).

However I'm interested in using ZFS. However, every tool I've tried only reports 2TB, and the `hdparm -N` output for reporting max sectors is sketchy:

```
$ uname -a
Linux nuthouse 3.2.0-49-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 17:39:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dmesg | fgrep sde
[2505154.456871] sd 5:0:0:0: [sde] 488370432 4096-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[2505154.460111] sd 5:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page present
[2505154.460117] sd 5:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[2505154.508410]  sde: sde1 sde9

$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sde

/dev/sde:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 04 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 04 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 0/1, HPA is enabled

$ sudo parted /dev/sde print
Model: WD My Book 1140 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

$ sudo gdisk /dev/sde
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sde: 488370432 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2B18FE55-5944-2946-A9C6-69C21EFEEAB8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 488370426
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 488370421 sectors (1.8 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 488370421 free sectors (1.8 TiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 488370421 (1.8 TiB) in size.

Command (? for help): q

$ sudo zpool create tank /dev/sde

$ sudo zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  1.81T   576K  1.81T     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

$ sudo parted /dev/sde print
Model: WD My Book 1140 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      8389kB  2000GB  2000GB               zfs
 9      2000GB  2000GB  67.1MB

$ sudo gdisk /dev/sde
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sde: 488370432 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2B18FE55-5944-2946-A9C6-69C21EFEEAB8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 488370426
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2293 sectors (9.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       488353791   1.8 TiB     BF01  zfs
   9       488353792       488370175   64.0 MiB    BF07

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 2293 free sectors (9.0 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 2042 (8.0 MiB) in size.

Command (? for help): q
```

How should I proceed? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Was there already a partition table on the disk when you ran `zpool create ...` ? (there is no `zfs pool create` command)

Comment: Oops, thanks, fixed. I can't remember for certain the original state, but I just went into parted and deleted everything I could see. parted still reports the whole thing at 2TB. Pasting the output into my original question.

Comment: Your disk is reported as a 2000GB one. What says `dmesg|grep sde`? If correct, I would destroy the pool, blank the first sectors of the disk to remove the GPT partition table then create again the pool.

Comment: @jlliagre Pasted. It also reports 2TB. How do I blank the first sectors of the disk?

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=1M count=1` should do it

Comment: If dmesg reports a 2 TB disk, clearing the GPT is unlikely to help. My first guess would be either your disk is actually a 2 TB one or your controller firmware/BIOS doesn't handle bigger than 2 TB disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `parted` is reporting the disk as being 2000GB, blanking the partition table is unlikely to help. (Those size reports are based on the size of the hardware and are unrelated to what's in the partition table.) It's more likely that something has set the [Host Protected Area (HPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) for the disk, thus limiting its apparent size. You can adjust this with the Linux `hdparm` command, and in particular its `-N` option. (Type `man hdparm` and search on `-N` to find the details.) Typing `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sde` will report the current HPA status without changing it, so try that as a diagnostic.

Another possibility is that there's something wrong in the disk hardware or software stack. Your `parted` output indicates that you've got a WD My Book 1140. A Web search on this suggests that this is an external hard disk. Sometimes they can be problematic because of USB stack problems. Usually, though, such problems are issues with the firmware in the enclosure -- if the enclosure has a 32-bit limit on sector numbers, it will do weird things to the apparent size of the disk. In this case, though, it would be shocking if WD were to ship inadequate firmware with an over-2TiB disk, so this is plausible only if you've replaced the disk in the enclosure with a larger model yourself. Still, there could be a problem somewhere along these lines, especially if you're using an unusual USB adapter or something like that. It might be worth describing your hardware in more detail (both the drive and the motherboard or whatever type of adapter to which it's connected).

One more diagnostic to try is `gdisk`: Launch `gdisk` on the disk, type `p`, `v`, and then `q` to quit. Post the *complete* results. It's unlikely that this will provide any big clues, but there's an off chance that it will do so. You may need to install `gdisk` first (it's in either the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` package; I don't recall which name Ubuntu uses, offhand).

---

**Edit:** Your `hdparm -N` output is weird. Perhaps the enclosure's firmware isn't passing through that feature correctly. OTOH, the output does indicate that HPA is active, so it might be worth digging into that further with other utilities. (Maybe something Windows-based from the disk's manufacturer would fare better, especially if the disk is odd in some way.)

The `gdisk` output doesn't provide any new clues, although I did notice something I hadn't the first time around: The disk uses 4096-byte logical sectors. This means that you could use MBR on the disk, despite its size. (With 4096-byte sectors, MBR's limit goes up to 16TiB.) Using MBR isn't likely to help you because of the underlying problem that Linux is mis-detecting its size, though.

I have a few suggestions for things to try now:

- Return the disk and get another one, if it's new enough.
- Contact the manufacturer for tech support.
- Try the disk with Windows and/or OS X. This will give you information about whether the problem is OS-specific.
- Try another Linux distribution or another kernel. This might help if there's a Linux kernel bug involved.
- Try using another interface -- for instance, if you're using USB and if the drive supports eSATA, try eSATA.

Try these in any order that you like.

Comment: First, thanks - this is very informative! (1) I added the `hdparm -N` output to my orig. question - I'm not entirely sure what to make of it since 0 and 1 don't seem like proper sector counts, and Googling didn't turn up anything useful. Should I try setting it to 1? (Not worried about losing data on this device.) (2) I never replaced the enclosure. (3) I added the gdisk output, which just reports 2TB still.

Comment: I guess some related questions are how to check that my system/BIOS actually would be able to handle >2TB disks OK, and what would happen if I disable HPA but my system can't handle it.

Comment: See my above edits.

Comment: This has been super-informative. I'm just going to mark your answer as accepted and will report back my findings as I dig into this. Thanks!